# Definite article with "Wiener filtering", an uncountable noun

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, uncountable-nouns

I have a sentence something like this

> We apply Wiener filtering to obtain a solution.

In this "Wiener filtering" is a uncountable noun. I am not sure whether "the" is required before it.

Comment: In almost every case I can think of, I'd say that _the_ is unnecessary. "The" is a determiner, as is "Wiener" in this phrase, & there's normally no need for a second determiner, except when distinguishing one type of filtering from another, and even then it's probably not necessary. Depends on context -- eg, a desire to emphasize, as Robusto pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the article or not. It is a matter of choice. Normally it wouldn't be necessary unless you mean to set off the noun for some particular emphasis. For example, if you were speaking of several types of filtering and wanted to emphasize that this specific filtering is of the Wiener variety, especially if that choice were unusual or unexpected.